# Реализация по очереди с помощью Cron

Tags: php, алгоритм, cron, случайные-числа

В базе данных у меня есть таблица **tasks** и в ней столцы **id**, **url**, **num**. В данной таблице 3 записи.

Каков алгоритм составления с помощью cron и php следующего:

> Каждую минуту во всех 3 записях, столбец **num** будет принимать рандомные значения (функция rand())? То есть редактировать каждую из записей и заносить рандомные значения. А в случае, если добавилась новая запись, то работать и с ней.

Собственно хотелось, чтобы кто-нибудь написал просто алгоритм. Код я уже буду сам писать по алгоритму.

Comment: Алгоритм простой: раз в минуту запускать скрипт на PHP, который бы обновлял столбец num, присваивая ему случайное значение. Код пишется по этому алгоритму :)

Comment: @klopp, а если записей много? Как на это повлияет?

Comment: Алгоритм тот же.

Comment: @klopp, Вы не поняли... А если записей 1000, то это же ужас, в минуту обновлять столько записей...

Comment: Во-первых, не ужас и 100 тысяч. А во-вторых, вы чего хотите-то? Определитесь тогда с постановкой задачи, что ли.

Comment: @klopp, то есть 100к запросов это нормально, да? А каков например алгоритм, чтобы сначала первые 30 изменяло, потом ещё 30 и т.д..

Comment: Какие такие 100k запросов, откуда? Один, конечно же.

Comment: @klopp, Вы пишите, что не ужас и 100 тысяч, а тут я спрашиваю и странное удивление. Вообщем: 

>> А каков например алгоритм, чтобы сначала первые 30 изменяло, потом ещё 30 и т.д..

Comment: Сохраняем где-нибудь счетчик, а дальше "LIMIT $старт, $стоп". Задачу вижу, а вот проблему так и не нашел...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вставка во все записи таблицы в указанный столбец случайных чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 100000:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4949e/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (i int);

insert into t values
  (1), (2), (3);

update t set i = rand() * 100000;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4949e/1/0)**:

```
|     i |
|-------|
| 93786 |
| 95006 |
| 93672 |
```